# How to add fruit juice without splashing

Tags: sour, fruit-extract

I want to add fruit juice into my primary fermenter, but preferably want to do this with minimal splashing. Does anyone have any good technique or tips for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is really just to avoid splashes then just a funnel angled to one side while also angling the fermenter slightly, that would make the juice run smoothly down the side.

If it is to avoid any oxidation then I'd suggest an auto siphon and some tubing so air contact can be avoided all together.
A less ideal version, using the same principle, would be using a turkey baster or syringe (possibly also with tubing attached, depending on the fermenters size).

If you are still doing primary fermentation there should be a lot of CO2 and other heavy gasses in your fermenter, so oxidation shouldn't really be a big concern.